# Openshift oc cluster up fails to connect to 127.0.0.1:8443

Tags: openshift, okd

About OpenShift. I downloaded and unpack the last version of okd (from https://www.okd.io/download.html#oc-platforms)
After, just "oc cluster up"

Apart initial problems due to permissions and to --insecure-registry to be added to docker config, the "installation"/"containers starts" seems to be ok.
But at the end the connection on localhost:8443 is refused.

The linux is a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running on a Vmware workstation VM.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks, Lorenzo

[image]

Comment: Same problem. Expecting it to just work but it doesn't. I don't think they should boldly place the oc cluster up command on the website without testing if it actually works.